# Error developing phonegap cordova 2.2.0 plugin for android

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to write a PhoneGap Cordova 2.2.0 plugin for Android, but I'm having issues, and I'm unsure what the cause is.

Here is my JS:

**PushCapure.js**

```
var PushCapture = { 
        init : function () { 
            console.log('Attempting to call the PushCapture plugin');
            return cordova.exec(function() {
                alert('PushCapture was successful');
            }, function(error) {
                alert('PushCapture failed');
            }, "PushCapture", "capture", []);
        } 
};
```

Now here is my native code I want to run

**com.ron.camanon.PushCapture.java**

```
package com.ron.camanon;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import android.util.Log;

public class PushCapture extends CordovaPlugin {  

    public void capture()
    {
        Log.i("PushCapture", "PushCapture called, capture video stream intended...");
    }
}
```

This isn't working for me, I've also added this line to my **res/config.xml** :

```
<plugin name="PushCapture" value="com.ron.camanon.PushCapture"/>
```

The error callback is the only thing that is executed when I try my plugin.

What am I doing wrong?

This is Cordova 2.2.0 for Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't how the plugins work in Android, looks like you are using the iOS model where it calls a certain method.  In Android the "method" or specific command for the plugin will be sent as a string within the exec function see the code example below from the [Phonegap tutoral for plugins on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android)

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        this.beep(args.getLong(0));
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
    return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
}
```